# Create a form view, without useing the wizard

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Alright so I want to create a form, where the text in the textboxs will be sent to my database, after the user hits sumbit. The problem I am facing is i am used to using a detailsview or formview to do this for me, but how can I do this myself, where I manuelly update my database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, write  in OnLoad event code which will generate all controls which are needed.